# parse json with a callback function in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am firing a request through my android application using HttpPost , as the request is returning a JSON Callback function , i don't know how to handle it and parse it.

returned format:

```
handleEmployeeResponse({
  "records": [
    {
      "fullDesc": "Records for employe",
      "id": "Emp_1",
      "name": "Jack"
    }
  ]
});
```

in a firebug i can see as a response text

> handleEmployeeResponse({"records":[{"fullDesc":"Records for
>   employe","id":"Emp_1","name":"Jack"}]});

if i will parse the above response using JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString); i am surely gonna get JSON parsing error as the above response is not valid json at all so i have to remove 
"handleEmployeeResponse , ( , ); " form the response string then i need to pass it so JSONObject
can anyone tell me how to parse json with a callback function in android

Comment: Use Google -> http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=parse+JSON+android

Comment: Is handleEmployeeResponse a Java function or is the code you posted all received text?

Comment: @Hunt by returning a JSON Callback function, do you mean a JSON string i.e. the one you posted ? or a POJO ?

Comment: it is a java function that returns as a response text

Comment: @olamotte handleEmployeeResponse({"records":[{"fullDesc":"Records for employe","id":"Emp_1","name":"Jack"}]}); this is how it returns from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your service is returning a response in the [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) format (JSON with Padding). You either need to regex out the JSON message, or find out a way to ask the service not to return the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) : you should use the JSONTokener Class and thus get a JSONObject corresponding to your structure.

[TOKENER](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html)

the example is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String at
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(responseString).nextValue()

Comment: @Hunt did you try with another JSON string ? Obviously the returned string as an overhead, and the valid JSON starts here : you should then truncate the string to : 
    {
  "records": [
    {
      "fullDesc": "Records for employe",
      "id": "Emp_1",
      "name": "Jack"
    }
  ]
}

if you have any doubt use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)